# On Linux, can you write to HFS+ extended attributes?

Tags: linux, filesystems, hfs+

I'm in the process of setting up a file server, and I'm looking for a way to preserve extended attributes in files that come from OS X machines, and manipulate them while the file is on the server.  Obviously (well, presumably) this will require using HFS+ on the server, which is not a problem (unless there are hidden downsides I should know about), but I'm concerned that the support for HFS+ is minimal and will either (1) not preserve these attributes, or (2) preserve them but require copying the file to an OS X machine to manipulate them.

How complete is the support for HFS+ in Linux?  Will I be able to do everything I've mentioned?

Comment: What type of file server are your planning on running? (E.g., Samba, NFS, etc.)

Comment: Without knowing how you're planning on serving the files its hard to know for sure, but you probably don't need to use HFS+. Your presumption is likely incorrect.

Comment: @derobert: FreeNAS (which includes AFP, NFS, Samba, etc.), if it will do what I need.  But any Linux (or BSD) product would be fine.

Comment: @derobert: are you suggesting that I can just push files with HFS+ extended attributes to the server and they'll be preserved no matter what FS is used on the server?  And that I can modify them from OS X clients?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use *any* filesystem, but the normal choices (e.g., ext4) should work. Netatalk for example can use filesystem extended attributes (which ext3, ext4, btrfs, etc. all support) or .AppleDouble files. Its been a while since I've done this, or I'd write up an answer for you...

Comment: The only reason I'd consider using HFS+ is if I intended to remove the disk from the Linux machine at some point, and plug it into a Mac. Other than that, I'd start by trying ext4, or btrfs if you're daring.

Comment: So I guess the remaining question is this: will the extended attributes from the client FS (HFS+) get translated to extended attributes on the NAS FS (ext4 or possibly ZFS) and make the round trip completely intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I do not believe that either the native HFS+ driver or the Paragon software HFS+ products support extended attributes.

According to the HFS+ Wikipedia page the status of these drivers is every basic in the features that they support and have been known to corrupt HDDs in certain situations.

*excerpt from [CentOS thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.centos.general/124223)*

> On Wednesday, March 07, 2012 01:17:15 PM Wessel van der Aart wrote:
>
> > so i add user_xattr and acl to my fstab options but then it fails to mount.
> >     checking the error in dmesg just gives me ¨hfs: unable to parse mount 
> >     options¨.
> >     does anyone know what´s going on and what i should do to make this work?
>
> Well, having used the in-kernel HFS+ filesystem driver before, and
>   found it lacking in a number of areas (like massive corruption under
>   heavy load or when unlinking lots of files) I bought the commercially
>   supported Paragon NTFS&HFS drivers.

*excerpt from [CentOS thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.centos.general/124223)*

> i tried their free version today. at first it did look promising but
>   as soon i was to perform actions on  files with acl's on them the
>   whole system came down hard and leaving my  external HDD corrupted.
>   after several hours i've decided to give up and go with ext4 but still
>   thanks!

#### References

- [HFS+ Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Linux)
- [hfs with extended attribute support](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.centos.general/124223)